# Java - Overriding A Parent Class Method

Tags: java, methods, overriding, parent-child, superclass

I am new to Java and I am working on a project that works with calculating prices with/without employee discounts.  After reading the following code could someone explain to me how I might go about changing the parent class method outputs from the child class in order to get the correct outputs for my program?

**Parent Class (I am NOT allowed to edit this):**

```
public class GroceryBill {
    private Employee clerk;
    private List<Item> receipt;
    private double total;
    private double internalDiscount;

    public GroceryBill(Employee clerk) {
        this.clerk = clerk;
        receipt = new ArrayList<Item>();
        total = 0.0;
        internalDiscount = 0.0;
    }

    public void add(Item i) {
        receipt.add(i);
        total += i.getPrice();
        internalDiscount += i.getDiscount();
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return Math.rint(total * 100) / 100.0;
    }

    public Employee getClerk() {
        return clerk;
    }

    public void printReceipt() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    private String valueToString(double value) {
        value = Math.rint(value * 100) / 100.0;
        String result = "" + Math.abs(value);
        if(result.indexOf(".") == result.length() - 2) {
            result += "0";
        }
        result = "$" + result;
        return result;
    }

    public String receiptToString() {
        String build = "items:\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < receipt.size(); i++) {
            build += "   " + receipt.get(i);
            if(i != receipt.size() - 1) {
                build += "\n";
            }
        }
        return build;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return receiptToString() + "\ntotal: " + valueToString(total);
    }

    public String discountToString() {
        return receiptToString() + "\nsub-total: " + valueToString(total) + "\ndiscount: " + valueToString(internalDiscount) + "\ntotal: " + valueToString(total - internalDiscount);
    }

    public static class Employee {
        private String name;

        public Employee(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private String name;
        private double price;
        private double discount;

        public Item(String name, double price, double discount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.discount = discount;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public double getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }

        private String valueToString(double value) {
            String result = "" + Math.abs(value);
            if(result.indexOf(".") == result.length() - 2) {
                result += "0";
            }
            result = "$" + result;
            return result;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + valueToString(price) + " (-" + valueToString(discount) + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my code:**

```
public class DiscountBill extends GroceryBill
{
    private int myDiscountCount;
    private double myDiscountAmount;
    private double myPrice;

    public DiscountBill(Employee clerk, boolean preferred)
    {
        super(clerk);

        String name = "";
        double price = 0;
        double discount = 0;

        Object myItem = new Item(name, price, discount);
        myPrice = ((GroceryBill.Item) myItem).getPrice() - ((GroceryBill.Item) myItem).getDiscount();

        GroceryBill.Item myBill = new GroceryBill.Item(name, price, discount);
        myDiscountAmount = myBill.getDiscount();

        if (myDiscountAmount > 0 && preferred)
        {
            myDiscountCount++;
        }
    }
    /*
    public double getTotal()
    {
        Override goes here?
    }
    */
    public int getDiscountCount()
    {
        return myDiscountCount;
    }
    public double getDiscountAmount()
    {
        return myDiscountAmount;
    }
    public double getDiscountPercent()
    {
        return (myPrice / getDiscountCount()) * 100;
    }
}
```

**Lastly, [here](http://prntscr.com/7wv4vg) is the expected output:**

P.S. Please let me know if I need to give more/less information and ways that I can clean up this post or make it easier to understand.  If my question was too broad, please ask me what you don't understand about it and I'll try my best to tell you!  Thank you!

Comment: which method you want to override of `Parent` class?

Comment: What output you expect?

Comment: @Ankit Nigam  I think i might need to override the getTotal() method in order to change the value from 1.35 to 1.1 which is shown in the screenshot i provided at the end of my post.

Comment: @TheCodingFrog the expected output is shown in the screenshot linked near the end of my post in bold.  I expect getTotal to be 1.1, but it stays 1.35 and there are other values, such as the getDiscountCount that need to be correct also.

Comment: so think of it this way, you want the behavior of `getTotal` method to change if it is a discount bill. (your total gets discounted). So you would need to _override_ what it did before. Also you can just use the result from earlier by using `super.getTotal()` in the child class. Is this what you needed to know? (to see how too override a method, [see here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm))

Comment: @Aarjav I don't quite see what you mean.  I need to be able to change the total that the parent class gets from the add(Item i) method from the child class that I am in.  At least I think that's what I need to do because I don't know how else I could get the output to be 1.1 instead of 1.35 like it shows in the expected output screenshot I provided.

Comment: Elsewhere in the code, such as the main method where it is doing the testing, A `DiscountBill` object maybe referred to as a `GroceryBill`. but when you call some methods on that object, the `DiscountBill` 's version will be ran. This is why you are not allowed to edit `GroceryBill`, you simply need to "rewrite" the methods that behave differently in `DiscountBill`. see the link in the earlier comment for an example.

Comment: @Aarjav I understand the basics of overriding, but what I'm asking is how I would override int his case.  In my DiscountBill class my "myPrice" and "myDiscountAmount" variables are 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: `myDiscountAmount` is never updated, maybe you want to update it every time an Item is added to the bill. As for `myPrice`, I think it safe to just get rid of the variable all together and use the `getTotal` method instead

Comment: @Aarjav Yes I know that, but what I'm asking is how?  I already have myDiscountAmount = myBill.getDiscount();    shouldn't that be updating it?

Comment: That is being done in the constructor, so it only runs once: when the object is first created. Also if you just follow the code for it you'll see that it's ultimately getting its value (of 0) from the `discount` variable in the constructor. All that logic should be in the `add` method (Overriden), except for the `Object item = ...` which you can get rid of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84271/discussion-between-trafton-and-aarjav).